# Setting-up a script in javascript with radio-button

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have some radio-buttons for some article categories :

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="France" id="france" checked>France
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="Monde" id="monde">Monde
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="Culture" id="culture">Culture
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="Sports" id="sports">Sports
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="Economie" id="economie">Economie
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="Régions" id="regions">Régions
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="France" id="divers">Divers
    </label>
</div>
```

The categories are in an array called " $afamilyNews "

So now, I would like to set up a script javascript to show the right category when the radiobutton is clicked.
Can you help me do that ? Or give me some lead ?

Thanks a lot for your time, explanations and patience.

Comment: What do you mean by "right category"?

Comment: if I click "france" radio button for example, I want the articles with the category "france" and not the others

Comment: What does the array look like?

Comment: for example the first position of the array look like this : 
"_0_":{
"id":"1217",
"id_parent":"0",
"IDSociety":"184",
"public_id":"4",
"title":"Culture",
"family_code":"",
"aImage":{
"_1_":{
"id":1,
"order":1,
"title_fr":"eiffel-tower-3349075_1920",
"url":"/i/p-8-4-4-Fnews184_12023_4_1.png"
}

Comment: I thought it would be great to use if condition

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's $.getScript() function will perform your jo.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

```
$(".btn-primary").click(function() {
   $.getScript("Monde.js");
});
```

Please try with this.

Comment: The categories are not in a js file. that's in an array